# Why can't I empty array within class with bound method?

Tags: javascript

Below I have the `Example` class with two bound methods `reset` and `addItem`. I'd expected this code to log `0` but instead it logs `4`. I'm curious as to why this is happening, and if there is a way to have it work the way I'd expect.

```js
class Example {
   array = []
   constructor () {
      this.reset = this.reset.bind(this)
      this.addItem = this.addItem.bind(this)
   }
   reset () {
      this.array = []
   }
   addItem () {
      this.array.push('hello')
   }
}

const {array, reset, addItem} = new Example()

addItem()
addItem()
addItem()
addItem()

reset()

console.log(array.length)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this line

```
const {array, reset, addItem} = new Example()
```

you're extracting the *current references* of `array`, `reset`, and `addItem` when the object is instantiated. If you reassign one of the properties of the object later, the previous references will not change by themselves to point to the new value. For the same reason, the following logs 1, not 2.

```js
const obj = { num: 1 };
let { num } = obj;
obj.num = 2;
console.log(num);
```

For your code, you could make a method named `getArray`

```js
class Example {
   array = []
   constructor () {
      this.reset = this.reset.bind(this)
      this.addItem = this.addItem.bind(this)
   }
   getArray = () => this.array;
   reset () {
      this.array = []
   }
   addItem () {
      this.array.push('hello')
   }
}

const {getArray, reset, addItem} = new Example()

addItem()
addItem()
addItem()
addItem()

reset()

console.log(getArray().length)
```

Or you could mutate the array instead of reassigning it in `reset`.

```js
class Example {
   array = []
   constructor () {
      this.reset = this.reset.bind(this)
      this.addItem = this.addItem.bind(this)
   }
   reset () {
      this.array.length = 0;
   }
   addItem () {
      this.array.push('hello')
   }
}

const {array, reset, addItem} = new Example()

addItem()
addItem()
addItem()
addItem()

reset()

console.log(array.length)
```

Comment: this `getArray` solution works thanks